# How to prevent a React app crashes when an object is passed as null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have in my React app a situation where an object called site is passed as a null object.
This provokes the app to crash and I don't know how to handle this. The site object can be null in specific situations so I have to not let the app crash when a null object comes.

I have this example

```
const Sites = ({
  isOpen,
  onClose,
  site,
  onChange: onChangeSelectedSite = () => {},
}) => {
  
  <CODE>
  const preparedSites = useMemo(
    () =>
      sites
        .sort(sortSiteSelection(site))
        .map(elm => {
          const arr = [
            elm.siteId,
            elm.city,
            elm.state,
            elm.country,
            elm.address,
            elm.status,
          ];
          if (nearestSites.length)
            arr.push(
              nearestSites.find(s => s.closestSiteId === elm.siteId).distance,
            );
          return arr;
        })
        .sort((a, b) => a[6] - b[6]),
    [sites, site, nearestSites],
  );
  
  <code>

}
```

The above code is what receive site ad on that line `.sort` crashes as `site === null`.

The site is passed from the following parent

```
const SitesChangeButton = ({ site, onChange }) => {
  <code>
  <Sites
        site={site}
        isOpen={isOpenNew}
        onClose={onCloseNew}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
}
```

The site object when present have

```
{
   siteId,
   city,
   state,
   country,
   address,
   status,
}
```

When an object is null as obvious we have errors as the above items are null like status is null as an example.

If it is necessary to show more details let me know in the comments

Adding the sort functionality with the suggested fix but still not working

```
import { pipeSort } from '../fp';

const nameCompare = (x, y) => x.name.localeCompare(y.name);
const cityCompare = (x, y) => x.city.localeCompare(y.city);
const compareCountry = s => (x, y) => {
  if (!s) return 0;

  if (x.countryCode === s.countryCode && y.countryCode === s.countryCode)
    return 0;
  else if (x.countryCode === s.countryCode) return -1;
  else if (y.countryCode === s.countryCode) return 1;
  else return x.countryCode.localeCompare(y.countryCode);
};

export const sortSiteSelection = selectedSite => {
  if (!selectedSite) {
    console.log('NULL FROM SORT SITE');
    return 0;
  }
  pipeSort(compareCountry(selectedSite), nameCompare, cityCompare);
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How you'd handle `null` entirely depends on what you want the component to *do* when the value is `null`.  For example, if the `<Sites/>` component shouldn't render at all, you'd indicate that:

```
const SitesChangeButton = ({ site, onChange }) => {
  <>
    {site &&
      <Sites
        site={site}
        isOpen={isOpenNew}
        onClose={onCloseNew}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    }
  </>
}
```

Or perhaps you'd display the component but have it internally handle `null`, such as returning `null` for `preparedSites`:

```
const preparedSites = useMemo(
  () => site ?
    sites.sort.....
    : null,
  [sites, site, nearestSites],
);
```

Or perhaps you'd handle `null` within `sortSiteSelection` (wherever that's defined), something like:

```
if (site === null) {
  return () => 0; // all values have the same sort result
}
```

---

Basically, and I guess this is a very generic statement for programming in any language anywhere... Wherever you want your logic for handling `null` to be, and whatever you want that logic to be, that's what you'd write in the code.

Comment: Good question, the Sites is a table that has to be present as a user needs to select a site there. In specific situations, we have site a preselected for the user in some none so the obj comes null but we have to render the table containing the sites where a user can select a site.

Comment: The problem with the above solutions is that what is in prepared sites is passe then to populate the table with the sites. Making at `site ? .. : null` crashes the table as the table expects those elements to be rendered.

Comment: @Jakub: Then perhaps you need to handle `null` within the `sortSiteSelection` function.  Something like `if (site === null) { return 0; }`.  So the function still "sorts" but all records have the same sort value if the input to the function is `null`.  Or within `preparedSites` only conditionally call `sortSiteSelection` based on whether `site` is `null`.  Again, the logic is really up to you.  There's no single solution to "handle null" in all possible situations, it depends on what logic you want to perform.

Comment: yes maybe I will do it here in the sortSiteSelection
https://pastebin.com/jT02CUne

Comment: If you can take a look at my shared link about sortSite because I tried to apply your suggestion but the app crashes with the same result and seems return 0 just does anything :(

Comment: @Jakub: What specific code is producing the error, which line throws the error, and what is the exact error?

Comment: this crashes only when site is null when we have the object all works fine

Comment: @Jakub: Maybe `sortSiteSelection` needs to return a function instead of a value?  I've updated the answer with a guess.  Ultimately at this point it's primarily a guess what any given function in your code *should* be returning, but you should be aware of the expected return types/values.  (As an aside, using TypeScript will help you with keeping return types consistent.)